# NGINX support both subdomains and normal

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Not an NGINX guru but I've made the changes that I believe will work. This is PROD server so don't just want to push to it and hope for the best.

What I'm trying to do is have both subdomains and domains redirect to it's respective pages. For example when someone enters https://example.com I need it to do to https://example.com when someone enters https://learning.example.com I need it to go to https://learning.example.com and finally when someone enters https://www.learning.example.com i need server to redirect to https://learning.example.com. If all that makes sense.

Below code I believe (but could be wrong) should be working, but would appreciate If someone could review it and fix potential issues that might cause.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name *.example.com;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                return ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES8:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name *.example.com;
        server_tokens off;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
        gzip_min_length  500;
        gzip_buffers  4 32k;
        gzip_types  text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml image/svg;
        gzip_vary on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 365d;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @nodejs;
        }

        location @nodejs {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }

        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}
```

Comment: You should have a staging environment where you actually test the configuration.

Comment: I don't that is the problem. Dev -> Prod. Poor practice I know but I'm the only one working on it and until now there wasn't any issues.

Comment: Well, I read your post that the changes were being made directly to production server...

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your second `server` block.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

`$host` in this case would resolve to the `server_name`, which means this will cause a redirect loop.

To redirect from `www.` prefix to host without prefix, you need to use a regular expression in the `server_name`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name ~^www\.(?<domain>.+)$;

    ...
    return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;
}
```

The regular expression is used to capture the bare domain name, and then issue the redirect to the actual domain.

Comment: And the rest look ok? I'll try and push the changes to prod when traffic going to die down a little. :) Will keep you in the loop

Comment: Didn't see other issues.

Comment: Didn't work. server just crashed after rebuild :/ Will need to investigate the logs